# Uncaught ReferenceError: classroom1 is not defined

Tags: javascript

```
function classroom(teacherName, studentCount, homeworkSubmitted, homeworkAssigned) {
    var classroom1 = new classroom("Denise", 50, 45, 45);
    var classroom2 = new classroom("Connie", 20, 20, 45);
    var classroom3 = new classroom("Becky", 10, 15, 45);
}
var schoolAverage = new schoolHwAverage([classroom1.teacherName, classroom2.teacherName, classroom3.teacherName], [classroom1.studentCount + classroom2.studentCount + classroom3.studentCount], [classroom1.homeworkCount = classroom2.homeworkCount + classroom3.homeworkCount]

);
```

Comment: this is little bit confusing. you cant refer classroom1 outside the function.

Comment: At first, I would recommend you to start with a description of what are trying to achieve and what is the expected result of your code.

Comment: What's your question? Why you're getting that, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move all classroom1,2 and 3 outside the classroom function.

```
var classroom1 = new classroom("Denise", 50, 45, 45);
var classroom2 = new classroom("Connie", 20, 20, 45);
var classroom3 = new classroom("Becky", 10, 15, 45);

function classroom(teacherName, studentCount, homeworkSubmitted, homeworkAssigned) {
   return{
      teacherName,
      studentCount,
      homeworkSubmitted,
      homeworkAssigned
   }
}
var schoolAverage = new schoolHwAverage([classroom1.teacherName, classroom2.teacherName, classroom3.teacherName], [classroom1.studentCount + classroom2.studentCount + classroom3.studentCount], [classroom1.homeworkCount = classroom2.homeworkCount + classroom3.homeworkCount]

);
```

Comment: Both actually, I think I got the answer, new to js and trying to determine why code is not working